# In search of such "miraculous" triangle doublets

Tags: number-theory, triangles, integers

Here is a simple question, but the answer is fairly unexpected.

> Which of the following triangles has the larger inscribed circle?
>
> A. the triangle with sides 17, 25, and 26
>
> B. the triangle with sides 17, 25, and 28

In fact, they have inscribed circles of the **same** size! In addition, the radius is an integer.

Such triangle doublets are "miraculous" since:

1. All of the six sides are positive integers.
2. One triangle has sides $a$, $b$ and $c$, while the other triangle has sides $a$, $b$ and $d$ ($c$ is not equal to $d$).
3. They have inscribed circles of the same size.
4. The radius of each of inscribed circles is a positive integer.

Obviously, if $(a,b,c)$ and $(a,b,d)$ can form such a doublet, then so can $(ka, kb, kc)$ and $(ka, kb,kd)$ for any positive integer $k$. As a result, only "primitive" examples matter.

One of my friend, who is good at programming, offered me some examples:

> {{{17,25,26},6},{{17,25,28},6}}
>
> {{{41,50,39},12},{{41,50,73},12}}
>
> {{{61,195,160},21},{{61,195,232},21}}
>
> {{{65,68,57},18},{{65,68,105},18}}
>
> {{{97,169,122},30},{{97,169,228},30}}
>
> {{{97,340,339},42},{{97,340,345},42}}
>
> {{{100,291,289},42},{{100,291,299},42}}
>
> {{{246,365,329},84},{{246,365,455},84}}
>
> {{{255,260,103},42},{{255,260,485},42}}
>
> {{{257,289,168},60},{{257,289,482},60}}
>
> {{{260,629,381},30},{{260,629,879},30}}
>
> {{{305,377,124},42},{{305,377,660},42}}
>
> {{{313,338,155},60},{{313,338,601},60}}
>
> {{{337,625,386},84},{{337,625,888},84}}
>
> {{{353,578,481},120},{{353,578,735},120}}
>
> {{{364,505,545},126},{{364,505,561},126}}
>
> {{{609,740,355},126},{{609,740,1241},126}}
>
> {{{623,884,807},210},{{623,884,1111},210}}
>
> {{{641,841,780},210},{{641,841,1082},210}}

It seems that such "primitive" solutions are infinite, but I can't prove it.

Besides, can we find a formula to generate some primitive solutions?

Comment: Are you aware of the very recent question on this site: (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2102886)?

Comment: But it seems that this very recent question concerns only Pythagorean triangles.

Comment: Primitive triangles can be sorted by their area radical.  http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TriangleRadicals/  You're looking at the Heronian triangles.  http://www.wm-archive.uni-bayreuth.de/index.php?id=554&L=3  has a long list.

Answer (score 0):

The radius equation for the incircle can be given by

$$r=\frac{\Delta}{s}=\frac{2\Delta}{a+b+c}$$

We can solve for c from the above equation by using ***Heron's formula*** for $\Delta$, given that $a_1=a_2=a,\ b_1=b_2=b,\ r_1=r_2=r$.

It is no surprise that the equation simplifies to a quadratic equation and in some cases may have ***two distinct real positive roots*** which state your case.

Hence we can have $c_1\ne c_2$, and the number of such triangles is infinite as we can form infinite quadratic equations which suits the above case.